# How to show date period in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I've table `User_LogTime` like this:

```
________________________________
|    Date    |  User ID | Name |
| 1 Jan 2019 |   00001  | Andy |
| 1 Jan 2019 |   00002  | Benn |
| 2 Jan 2019 |   00001  | Andy |
| 3 Jan 2019 |   00001  | Andy |
| 4 Jan 2019 |   00001  | Andy |
| 4 Jan 2019 |   00002  | Benn |
| 4 Jan 2019 |   00003  | Jack |
--------------------------------
```

I want make query result like this:

```
________________________________
|    Date    |  User ID | Name |
| 1 Jan 2019 |   00001  | Andy |
| 2 Jan 2019 |   00001  | Andy |
| 3 Jan 2019 |   00001  | Andy |
| 4 Jan 2019 |   00001  | Andy |
| 1 Jan 2019 |   00002  | Benn |
| 2 Jan 2019 |   null   | null |
| 3 Jan 2019 |   null   | null |
| 4 Jan 2019 |   00002  | Benn |
| 1 Jan 2019 |   null   | null |
| 2 Jan 2019 |   null   | null |
| 3 Jan 2019 |   null   | null |
| 4 Jan 2019 |   00003  | Jack |
---------------------------------
```

Date period set from query, result `group by User ID` and `sort by Date`.

What query to get that result?

Comment: Use a cte to get distinct dates from the table. left join that cte with the actual table. Order by userId then by date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to join with a calendar table which contains all dates you expect in the output.  I also assume that you have a user table somewhere, containing all user IDs.  For example:

```
WITH cal AS (
    SELECT '2019-01-01' AS dt UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-01-02' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-01-03' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-01-04'
)

SELECT c.dt, u.user_id, ult.name
FROM cal c
CROSS JOIN users u
LEFT JOIN User_LogTime ult
    ON c.dt = ult.Date AND u.user_id = ult.user_id
ORDER BY
    u.user_id,
    c.dt;
```

Comment: My problem has been solved. Thank you Tim.